# How to format two UIBarButtonItems next to each other on the right?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to format two UIBarButtonItems so that they are right next to each other in the upper right corner. I have already tried changing the UI Edge Insets, but it didn't really move the icons around. [Screenshot of current UI bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG2gO.png)

```
lazy var profileButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: UIImage(named: "account"),
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(displayAccountViewController(sender:))
)

lazy var followFriendsButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: UIImage(named: "follow"),
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(displayFollowFriendsViewController(sender:))
)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Review Feed"

    tableView.register(ReviewFeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [profileButton, followFriendsButton]

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadData), name: ShowCollector.updateNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: How big are the images you are using? I find 25x25 to be a good size.

Comment: @Sweeper the follow one is 512x512

Answer (score 1):

You should change size of your images.

Refer to Apple design guideline

[image] :